# How to filter foobar from all grep results of foo?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am searching a large codebase for all occurrences of the company acronym, which is a small 3-character word like `foo`. I normally do this sort of thing with

`grep -Rnoi 'foo' *`

starting at the top of the code base. However, since this is a small word that can produce an overwhelming amount of false positives, like 'foobar' or 'foocat', how might I go about filtering out the false positives?

I was thinking something along the lines of...

`grep -Rnoi 'foo' * | grep [excludeMagicOption] 'foobar'`

where the displayed results shows all foo occurrences without 'foobar'. What are some options for doing this?

Comment: use the `-w` `--word-regexp` option to match only the entire word `foo`

Comment: @nhahtdh the answer over there is inverted--excluding first then searching

Comment: @nhahtdh: the `-o` changes the `foobar` to `foo`, so `-v` won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a word boundary, denoted by `\b` in most (not all) Extended RE engines, and supported by `egrep` and `grep -E`.  This includes start and end of line, and non-alphas.

For example:  test.txt:

```
foo
foobar
foocat
foobar = foocat * 3
foobar = foo++
Feel the foo
What are the foo's price?
Strange how football changes.
Where is foo and bar?
```

Using:

```
grep -E '\bfoo\b' test.txt
```

Gives:

```
foo
foobar = foo++
Feel the foo
What are the foo's price?
Where is foo and bar?
```

Edit:  Some regular expression engines use other character sequences for word boundaries.  There is a summary here:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/refwordboundaries.html

Comment: this is awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for posting. I will be sure to use this next time!

Comment: To be precise, `\b` is a GNU extension. That's why it's not going to work in all systems.

Comment: @nhahtdh: not just GNU, `\b` is also supported by Perl (and hence PCRE), Python, and Ruby.

Comment: @cdarke Yes. I only explain why the command wouldn't be portable to any *nix system.

Comment: @nhahtdh: fair comment, I added a note

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question that you only want to match `foo` and not `foocat`, use the `-w` or `--word-regexp` option to match only whole word occurrences of `foo`. Example:

**Input file**

```
$ cat foo.txt
foo
foocat
foobar
foo
foofighter
```

**Use Output**

```
$ grep -Roniw 'foo' foo.txt
1:foo
4:foo
```

You can add more conditions to the initial regex to just match a set of whole words. From your example in the comment `foo` and `foo-`, you could use:

```
grep -Roniw 'foo[-]*' foo.txt
```

**Input file**

```
$ cat foo.txt
foo
foocat
foobar
foo
foofighter
foo-
```

**Use Output**

```
$ grep -Roniw 'foo' foo.txt
1:foo
4:foo
6:foo-
```

Comment: awesome, this is a more elaborate way to only find foo occurrences. but it doesn't seem to work if you want foo. or foo-, would it?

Comment: @JulianSoro: Please update your question to clarify your requirement. Having 2 answers with solution you don't want should tell you that your question is unclear.

Comment: @JulianSoro: Note that this answer will prevent `afoo` from matching (whether it's desired or not - only you know). As you can see, people are trying to read your mind whether you want to match with word boundary or not, and it is not at all clear what you categorize as false positive

Comment: @JulianSoro, sure you can, just broaden your `regex` (e.g.  `grep -Roniw 'foo[-]*' foo.txt`) See the updated answer. That way to don't have to `-v` exclude a whole bunch of different possible matches (if you are even lucky enough to know what they are beforehand)

Comment: @DavidCRankin Thanks, this worked good enough for me last night. However, I switched the answer because with this technique is less concise. I do appreciate the flexibility it offers...

Answer (score 0):

You want the `-v` option:

```
grep -Rnoi 'foo' * | grep -v 'foobar'
```

---

From `grep --help`:

```
-v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this?  The output from the first `grep` is modified by the `-Rnoi` options, specifically the `-o` option strips out the `foobar`, so this won't work  (I know, it would otherwise).